# Automatically unrolling and outputting for C/C++ code

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, llvm, cpu-architecture, icc

I'm doing an experiment and the first step is to unroll a loop (from C/C++) a dozen of times (ex: 10, 50, etc) and output the C/C++ unrolled code. Is there any tool that I can use to automatize such unrolling?

In other words, what I need is:

```
C/C++ source/loop --->> TOOL (Unroll by X) ---->  Unrolled C/C++ source/loop
```

Comment: I think most compilers/jitters perform this kind of optimization after the code was converted to some other representation that looks more like assembly (although usually still platform agnostic), it's much easier to perform analysis and apply changes in that form.

Comment: Do you need the unrolled source code to be readable and portable?

Comment: @Leeor: you are right. However for this experiment I need to manually change the code further.

Comment: @delnan: these aren't a big concern right now, because if I do not find a tool to do that automatically I will need to do it manually. So I can trade some time for portability / 'readability'.

Comment: I'd use the boost preprocessor library. It has a perfectly adequate (and somewhat surprising) implementation of an indexed repeater: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html It only goes up to 256 repetitions by default; if you need more, you'll need to find a different template solution. Hint: `gcc -E -P <file>` (or change `gcc` to `clang`) just preprocesses and outputs the results without the pesky `#line` directives, so you can use that as a "TOOL" in your diagram.

Comment: I hope you don't find this off topic, but I would prefer an in-code solution such as Duff's Device (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).

Comment: @SplinterOfChaos: The multiple loop entry points of Duff's Device are likely to defeat optimizations like auto-vectorization, and of reducing loop overhead by incrementing a pointer once for the whole loop and then using offsets.  Duff's Device is good on a machine with post-increment addressing modes, where efficient asm actually could look a lot like the C source, but that's not what you want for common ISAs like x86.

Answer (score 2):

Our source-to-source transformation engine, the
 [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](https://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html?site=StackOverflow), 
with its [C++17 front end](https://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html?site=StackOverflow) can be used to do this.

DMS can accept [explicit source-to-source transformation rules](https://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSRewriteRules.html?site=StackOverflow).

Individual rules are written as

```
rule rule_name(metavariables_with_syntax_categories)
:syntax_category->syntax_category
= left_hand_side_pattern_to_match 
-> right_hand_side_replacement_after_substitution
```

Below I provide an (untested) set that are pretty close to the mark.  These are directly inspired by the classic compiler optimization for unrolling a loop.

The ... inside "..." that you see means "(C++ syntax for) ..."; these are " here are domain text metaquotes, not C++ string quotes.
\foo inside "..." means metavariable foo, which represents a chunk (tree) of C++ code.
\bar(...\,...) means "metafunction bar invoked on ..."  Note the "metacommas" spelled \, and metaparentheses ( ) used to distinguish metafunctions from domain ("C++") syntax.
 See the link for more details on the syntax of such rules.

The unquoted patterns UNROLL and ReplaceIbyEXP define "metafunctions", which can be thought of as intentions to apply more tranformations.

Here UNROLL captures our notion that we want to repeat a block of code n times. There are two (effectively recursive) rules to implement this notion, one for the base case of "repeat zero times" producing an empty statement list, and the other generating the code block followed by repeating n-1 times.   ReplaceIbyEXP then adjusts the index i used in the copied code block.

```
external pattern ReplaceIbyEXP(s:statements,i:IDENTIFIER,r:expression):statements;

pattern UNROLL_1(s:statements,i:IDENTIFIER,k:INT_LITERAL,c:INT_LITERAL)
  :statements->statements;

rule UNROLL_1(s:statements,i:IDENTIFIER,d:INT_LITERAL,c:INT_LITERAL)
  :statements->statements
  = UNROLL(s,i,d,c) -> ";" if c=="0";

rule UNROLL_N((s:statements,i:IDENTIFIER,d:INT_LITERAL,c:INT_LITERAL)
  :statements->statements
  = UNROLL(s,i,d,c)
  -> "\ReplaceIbyEXP\(\s\,\i\,(\i+\d)\)
      \UNROLL\(\s,\i,\add\(\d\,1\),\subtract\(\c\,1\))" if c!="1";

rule UNROLL_FOR_k(i:IDENTIFIER,s:statements,limit:INT_LITERAL)
  :statements->statements
  = "for (\i=0;\i<\limit;\i++) { \s }"
  -> "for (\i=0;\i<\limit;\i+=k) { \UNROLL(\s\,\i\,0,k) }"
```

This code has a variety of hiccups to address:

- It doesn't express the implementation of ReplaceIbyEXP; at present, that needs
  to be realized by calling DMS's procedural ("PARLANSE") part ("external") to do a tree walk and replace each instance of the matching identifier with the provided subexpression.
  In the procedural part these are already trees and simple "AST:EqualNode" and "AST:ReplaceSubtree" can be used to realize it.  This is probably another 20 lines of PARLANSE code.
- It doesn't handle the case where the loop bound is not a multiple of k. That means there needs to be variants of UNROLL_FOR_k, one where the loop bound is a multiple (that's the one provided here) and the case where it isn't a multiple.  Then one needs to generate an unrolled loop of k copies, followed by cleanup code of  limit modulo k copies of the code.  (Alternatively, one can use something like Duff's device [mentioned in a comment on OP's question] on the first or last block of copies).
- One might want to supply k from the "outside".  That is easily implemented using another external pattern to fetch it.

Now, learning to use an engine like DMS is rather involved, partly you are dealing with C++ which is already extremely complicated, and partly because DMS's machinery has to be able to  handle all the peccadillos that C++ throws up.  [Clang will be equally hard to apply for the same reasons, but doesn't provide the pattern-driven transformation machinery].

So using DMS *just* to do this *once* is probably not a good use of your time.  If you have to automate this repeatedly, or do something much more complex reliably on a big code base, then it makes sense.  My two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Clang seemed like a good tool to do it since it's had a lot of hype around source-to-source transformation.  I looked up whether anyone had done source-to-source unrolling and found a project called Scout built on Clang that might implement what you need:

https://fusionforge.zih.tu-dresden.de/scm/viewvc.php/trunk/Scout/?root=hicfd&sortby=log&pathrev=151

Slides: http://tau.dlr.de/fileadmin/documents/meetings/2009/pdf/TU_Dresden_ZIH.pdf

Video: http://www.irill.org/videos/euro-llvm-2013/krzikalla-hires.webm